# Saving the score using shared preferences

Tags: android

Hey guys I know there are already many posts for the same and I have followed each of them.

Here I am facing a problem and need to know the sloution.

I am releasing my app tomorrow so need help with this.

I have tried to use it with string as well as int but none of them are working and giving error.

Thanks

My Code :

```
package com.droidacid.apticalc.tys;

import com.droidacid.apticalc.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HighScores extends Activity {

TextView tvHighScore;
private static String SCORE_KEY = "savedScore";
String myScore;
int score;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tys_high_score);
    tvHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tys_score);
    getScore();

}



private void getScore() {
    Bundle getScore = getIntent().getExtras();
    score = getScore.getInt("score");
    myScore = Integer.toString(score);
    setScore(score);
    getScore(score);

}

private void setScore(int score) {
    SharedPreferences saveScore = getSharedPreferences("saveScores",     MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveScore.edit();
    editor.putString(SCORE_KEY, myScore);
    editor.commit();

}
SharedPreferences saveScore = getSharedPreferences("saveScores", MODE_PRIVATE);
tvHighScore.setText(saveScore.getString(SCORE_KEY, ""));



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Post the error logs you got :)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: SharedPreferences saveScore = getSharedPreferences("saveScores", MODE_PRIVATE);
tvHighScore.setText(saveScore.getString(SCORE_KEY, ""));  . this lines are not in any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that these two lines are not in any method.

```
SharedPreferences saveScore = getSharedPreferences("saveScores", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

tvHighScore.setText(saveScore.getString(SCORE_KEY, ""));

Try to put these two lines in your on create method and you will see that this error will stop.
Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Even previously I was using it in getScore method...and it was giving error...now its ok...and now the score will get saved??

Comment: Also I tried to compare the current score with the score saved in the TextView so that if current score is more than previous score only then it will get saved...but not able to do so...so any help on that would be appreciated...

Comment: You should open a new question.
But no, these two line will only set the text but not save it for next launch.  any way, I dont see your setScore(score); method and what it does.

Comment: updated the question...also getting NullPointerExceotion error on setScore() method.